# Indenting in Codegear RAD Studio

Tags: c++, c++builder, indentation

Is there a way to indent/tab multiple lines in one action in the Codegear RAD Studio IDE?

i.e. I would like to be able to highlight multiple lines and indent them all by one tab simultaneously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seth

to indents selected code

Select the text and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

to unindents selected code

Select the text and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>

Bye.